# Tab Key Not working correctly in Primefaces Sheet Table

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

Tab key not working on primefaces sheet. If all fields are read only or editable tab key works i mean i can move to next field by pressing tab key. But if it is not same(one is read only and one is editable tab key not working). You can see on below i cannot move to next cell because one is read only and other is editable.

[image]

[image]

I tried to implement primefaces solution like giving scrollwidth to sheet but didnt work. How can i solve this issue ? @Melloware Need your help :)

My JSF VERSION : 2.2.1 PRİMEFACES AND PRIMEFACES EXTENSION VERSION : 6.2

Comment: TAB and SHIFT+TAB is working fine in the showcase: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/sheet/basicUsage.jsf

Your issue is that PFE 6.2 is 4 years old and many changes have been made to the sheet since

Comment: I tried with PF 6.2, without any theme, and the tab key works fine, is the problem that the tab key doesn't skip read-only cells? Or reaching a read-only cell then it doesn't work anymore?

Comment: @WoAiNii tab key doesnt skip if changed from read only to editable and vice versa. i have to jump next cell with mouse because tab key not skipping

Comment: Can you post a fully reproducible example?